# Не работает ссылка на наименование товара

Tags: php

Есть код случайного вывода картинки, нужно чтобы картинка стала ссылкой на наименование товара. при нажатии на ссылку, картинка ссылается сама на себя.

В остальных случаях эта ссылка работает, а вот здесь не хочет. Все данные о товарах хранятся в БД, а сами картинки на сервере в папке. Думаю, что надо добавить функцию или переменную, чтобы подцепить картинку к товару, только как это сделать не соображу, так как только учусь... пытаюсь учиться.

```
 $imageName="../images"; // картинки  
 $openthisdir=opendir($imageName);  
 while ($k=readdir($openthisdir)) {  
   $m=substr($k,-4);  
   if ($m=='.jpg' or $m=='.png' or $m=='.gif') $array[]=$k;  
   }  
 closedir($openthisdir);  
 $number=rand(0,count($array)-1);  
 echo "<a href='?type='><img src='$imageName/$array[$number]' WIDTH='150' HEIGHT='150' alt=''></a><br>";
```

Вот кусочки кодов с изображениями.

```
      $imageName = "/images/" . $type->type . ".jpg";
    if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $imageName)) {
    echo "<td style='padding-left:8px'><img border='0' src='" . htmlspecialchars($imageName, ENT_QUOTES) . "' alt='" . htmlspecialchars($type->name, ENT_QUOTES) . "' height='24'/></a></td>";
    }

//удаление изображения из папки    
  if (isset($_POST["del_type_image"])) {  
$fileName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/images/" . $_POST["del_type_image"] . ".jpg";  
unlink($fileName);  }

//добавление картинки к наименованию.    
if (isset($_POST["add_type_image"])) {  
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {  
$fileName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/images/" . $_POST["add_type_image"] . ".jpg";   
  copy($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $fileName);  }  }

// форма загрузки изображения и редактирования 
if ($edit) {    
echo "<form accept='image/jpeg' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' name='add_type_image' value='" . htmlspecialchars($mainType->type, ENT_QUOTES) . "'/>";    
echo "<label>Загрузить изображение:</label>";    
echo "<input type='file' name='image'/>";    
echo "<input type='submit' value='Загрузить'/>";    
echo "</form>";

// товар, на который должна ссылаться картинка из случайного изображения    
$imageName = "/images/" . $mainType->type . ".jpg";
if (file_exists($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $imageName)) {
        echo "<a href='$imageName'><img border='2' vspace='16' src='" . htmlspecialchars($imageName, ENT_QU OTES) . "' alt='" . htmlspecialchars($mainType->name, ENT_QUOTES) . "' width='256'/></a>";
  if ($edit) {
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='del_type_image' value='" . htmlspecialchars($mainType->type, ENT_QUOTES) . "'/>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Удалить изображение'/>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
}
```

Comment: А переменная с товаром-то где? Идентификатор какой-нибудь.

Перечитал. Блин. Дайте описание таблицы товаров (название, поля), как связывается товар с картинкой.

Вообще в общем случае *сначала* берется товар и по его ID уже делается все остальное.

Comment: Вы не в комментарии, а в ответ дописывайте)) 

И для форматирования кода выделите и нажмите кнопку с 101001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$imageName= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/"; // картинки, абс. путь  
$images = array();
foreach (scandir($imageName) as $f)
  // смотрим, есть ли расширение в списке
  if (in_array(substr($f, -4), array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')))
    // добавляем путь к картинке и имя файла без расширения
    $images[] = array('img' => '/images/'.$f, 'type' => substr($f, 0, -4));

$number=rand(0,count($images)-1);  
echo '<a href="?type='.$images[$number]['type'].'"><img src="'.$images[$number]['img'].'" width="150" height="150" alt=""></a><br />';
```

Comment: Большое спасибо... я бы вас наградила, но недостаточно очков уважения. Я так и знала, что истина где-то рядом. Еще раз спасибо. Вы меня очень выручили.... а можно узнать почему вы сделали именно так, ну в смысле обяснить можете что вы добавили в ссылку... и что за переменная $f. Очень большое желание выучить php. и побороть миф о блондинках.

Comment: @Екатерина Если ответ Вам помог, кликните по галочке под ладошкой вниз.

Comment: В последнем из кусков выше видно, что картинка называется так: `/images/%ТИП_ТОВАРА%.%РАСШИРЕНИЕ%`. Соответственно чтобы из картинки получить тип товара, надо отбросить расширение) Функцию scandir и in_array можете посмотреть на php.net $f - имя файла (только имя, "1.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

в предыдущем ответет вцелом код замечательный, но в данном участке кода:

```
... 
if (in_array(substr($f, -4), array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')))
...
```

не учтен случай, когда у файл может быть расширение длиной больше 3х символов (пр. "jpeg"), которое в процессе использования скрипта может быть добавлено в список разрешений, а также тот случай, когда название файла или только его расширение будет набрано в верхнем регистре, т.е. думаю, что было бы эффективней разбивать название по точке и приводить его к нижнему регистру:

```
...
// проверим имеем ли мы дело с файлом, а не директорией
// и в названии файла присутствует точка
if (!is_file($f) || (strpos($f, '.') == false)) {
    continue;
}
list($fname, $ext) = explode('.', $f, 2);
if (in_array(strtolower($ext), array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')))
...
```

ну, как-то так. Далее применить изменения по тексту алгоритма в связи с введением новых переменных. 
Есть достаточно примеров девушек программистов, так что удачи, дерзайте